# Android Studio on virtual Ubuntu 18 problem

Tags: android-studio, ubuntu, kotlin

I'm using Android Studio on Ubuntu 18 virtual machine, and my device disconnects from the VM when I launch the app on it.
What could I do to resolve it?

This is the error:

> 11/08 05:11:05: Launching 'app' on Unknown Device. The installation did not succeed. The application could not be installed. Installation
>   failed due to: 'device 'device's name' not found' Retry

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but i think that came from the fact i used a Ubuntu VM. I switched on Windows Vm. I'll resend for the result. Thanks all.